# How to move state outside of component using context provider

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I currently have a preview component which has a reloading functionality attached into it using the useState hook. I now want the ability to refresh this component with the same functionality but with an external component. I know that this can be achieved by the useContext API, however i'm struggling to plug it all together.

Context:

```
const PreviewContext = React.createContext({
    handleRefresh: () => null,
    reloading: false,
    setReloading: () => null
  });

const PreviewProvider = PreviewContext.Provider;
```

PreviewFrame:

```
const PreviewFrame = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const { height, width } = props;
  const classes = useStyles({ height, width });

  return (
    <Card className={classes.root} ref={ref}>
      <div className={classes.previewWrapper} > {props.children} </div>
      <div className={classes.buttonContainer}>
        <IconButton label={'Refresh'} onClick={props.toggleReload} />
      </div>
    </Card>
  );
});
```

PreviewFrameWrapped:

```
<PreviewFrame
   toggleReload={props.toggleReload}
   height={props.height}
   width={props.width}
   ref={frameRef}
>
  <PreviewDiv isReloading={props.isReloading} containerRef={containerRef} height={height} width={width} />
</PreviewFrame>

const PreviewDiv = ({ isReloading, containerRef, height, width }) => {
  const style = { height: `${height}px`, width: `${width}px`};
  return !isReloading ?
    <div className='div-which-holds-preview-content' ref={containerRef} style={style} />
    : null;
};
```

Preview:

```
export default function Preview(props) {

  const [reloading, setReloading] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setReloading(false);
  }, [ reloading ]);

  const toggleReload = useCallback(() => setReloading(true), []);

  return <PreviewFrame isReloading={reloading} toggleReload={toggleReload} {...props} />
}
```

So now i want to just be able to import the preview component and be able to refresh it using an external button, so not using the one that's already on the `<PreviewFrame>`.

I ideally want to consume it like this:

```
import { PreviewContext, PreviewProvider, Preview } from "../../someWhere"

<PreviewProvider>
    <Preview />
    <PreviewControls />
</PreviewProvider>

function PreviewControls () {
  let { handleRefresh } = React.useContext(PreviewContext);
  return <div><button onClick={handleRefresh}>↺ Replay</button></div>
}
```

Preview With My Attempt at Wrapping with Provider:

```
export default function Preview(props) {

  const [reloading, setReloading] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setReloading(false);
  }, [ reloading ]);

  const toggleReload = useCallback(() => setReloading(true), []);

  return (<PreviewProvider value={{ reloading: reloading, setReloading: setReloading, handleRefresh: toggleReload }} >
            <PreviewFrame isReloading={reloading} toggleReload={toggleReload} {...props} />
             {/* it works if i put the external button called <PreviewControls>  here*/}
          </PreviewProvider>
    );
}
```

So yeah as i said in the commented out block, it will work if put an external button there, however then that makes it attached/tied to the Preview component itself, I'm really not sure how to transfer the reloading state outside of the Preview into the Provider. Can someone please point out what i'm missing and what i need to do make it work in the way i want to.

Comment: It seems like you're close.  The trick will be to manage `reloading`, `setReloading` in `PreviewProvider`, which just wraps `children` and passes down the context.  Both `Preview` and `PreviewControls` both then pull the context from `useContext(PreviewContext)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do is to write a custom component PreviewProvider and store in the state of reloading and toggleReload function there. The preview and previewControls can consume it using context

```
const PreviewContext = React.createContext({
    handleRefresh: () => null,
    reloading: false,
    setReloading: () => null
  });
```

---

```
export default function PreviewProvider({children}) {

  const [reloading, setReloading] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setReloading(false);
  }, [ reloading ]);

  const toggleReload = useCallback(() => setReloading(true), []);

  return <PreviewContext.Provider value={{reloading, toggleReload}}>{children}</PreviewContext.Provider>
}
```

---

```
export default function Preview(props) {

  const {reloading, toggleReload} = useContext(PreviewContext);

  return <PreviewFrame isReloading={reloading} toggleReload={toggleReload} {...props} />
}
```

---

```
function PreviewControls () {
  let { toggleReload } = React.useContext(PreviewContext);
  return <div><button onClick={toggleReload}>↺ Replay</button></div>
}
```

---

Finally using it like

```
import { PreviewContext, PreviewProvider, Preview } from "../../someWhere"

<PreviewProvider>
    <Preview />
    <PreviewControls />
</PreviewProvider>
```